# Navigation pages links (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

How I can make navigations pages links in codeigniter.

Like this:

```
Main_page > page_1 > page_1_chiled
```

So the user can click any of these pages and go to it directly.

Thank you

Comment: Google for "breadcrumbs codeigniter" and you will most likely find many examples...

Answer (score 0):

Assume you controller name is `media`. And there are some methods

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Media extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function  __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function press()
        {
            # Press Relese
        }

        public function tele()
        {
            # Televistion Relses
        }

        public function social()
        {
            # Social realse
        }

    }
```

Create file call `breadcumb.php` in view. Inside

```
<? if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'Media') { ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?= base_url() ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li>&#187;</li>
        <li><a href="">Media</a></li>
        <li>&#187;</li>
        <li class="first">You Are Here</li>
    </ul>
<? } ?>
<? if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'Media' && $this->uri->segment(2) == 'press') { ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?= base_url() ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li>&#187;</li>
        <li><a href="">Media</a></li>
        <li>&#187;</li>
        <li><a href="">press</a></li>
        <li>&#187;</li>
        <li class="first">You Are Here</li>
    </ul>
<? } ?>
<? if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'Media' && $this->uri->segment(2) == 'tele') { ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?= base_url() ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li>&#187;</li>
        <li><a href="">Media</a></li>
        <li>&#187;</li>
        <li><a href="">tele</a></li>
        <li>&#187;</li>
        <li class="first">You Are Here</li>
    </ul>
<? } ?>
<? if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'Media' && $this->uri->segment(2) == 'social') { ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?= base_url() ?>">Home</a></li>
        <li>&#187;</li>
        <li><a href="">Media</a></li>
        <li>&#187;</li>
        <li><a href="">social</a></li>
        <li>&#187;</li>
        <li class="first">You Are Here</li>
    </ul>
<? } ?>
```